# Unhashable type: 'list' while working in a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, list, jupyter-notebook

Working on a csv file while using the stop_words function from NLTK why am i getting the error and how to fix it?

Working on a csv file while using the stop_words function from NLTK why am i getting the error and how to fix it?

````
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

narr=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\ narr.csv')
narr.head(5)
narr['Narration'].dropna(inplace=True)
tokens = narr['Narration'].apply(word_tokenize)

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
print(tokens)```



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-078c03604087> in <module>
     13 
     14 stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
---> 15 tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
     16 print(tokens)

<ipython-input-32-078c03604087> in <listcomp>(.0)
     13 
     14 stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
---> 15 tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
     16 print(tokens)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that tokens are a list of list, you cannot check if a list is in a set because mutable objects are not hashable usually.

You can try some solutions

Transform it to a tuple, but this is not gonna work if the tuple is not in stop_words:

```
tokens = [w for w in tokens if not tuple(w) in stop_words]
```

or, chain the tokens, but this is not gonna work if tokens is a mixup list with strings and other lists:

```
from itertools import chain
tokens = [w for w in chain.from_iterable(tokens) if not tuple(w) in stop_words]
```

or, **just make sure that tokens is a list of strings**